# How To Obtain toString of Different Files

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I am trying to create a small script in order to uglify javascript files easily and not have to do it through the command line every time an update is deployed. I'm trying to do it with [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js), but can't seem to get it to work. I have tried `require('');`'ing the files and then using that as the code to minify, but it seems to parse through it at some point, giving me errors as the code can't be ran by itself.

Is there a way to `toString()` this code in order to use it in my minification/uglification?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L5fzr67k/)  is a jsfiddle of one of the files I'm trying to minify. It gets stuck on the Sammy.apps.body part.

Comment: please provide your codes

Comment: @kiro112 Added a jsfiddle.